# Formatting top of worksheet of an old docx document?

Tags: formatting

[image]

Is there a way to recreate this graphic (docx) with LateX?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Anything is possible. How much of that is on every page?

Comment: just on the first page. It is an estimated 1/9 or 1/10 of the whole page.

Comment: Everything above the line appears to be a header.  Otherwise just use a tcolorbox, and possibly `\raisebox{0.4\headsep}[0pt]{...}`.

Answer (score 1):

If this is only for the first page, there are no need of make a header, but a simple table in the main text area:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{-1.5in}
{\raggedleft 
LOGO\par WS 2013/2014\par}
\tabcolsep0pt\extrarowheight1ex
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
\hline\cellcolor{cyan!40}       
\centering\large\scshape\bfseries Foo / Foo foo\par 
Foo - Foo
\end{tabular}\medskip\par
\noindent{\sffamily\small \hyperlink{Deadline}{Deadline}: yesterday}


\section{Infroduction to foo}\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Deadline}\label{Deadline}
\noindent\cleaders\hbox to 1em {\font\omding=omding \omding \char194} \hfill{}
\end{document}
```